# FLUTTER Hideable Overlay Menu

Tags: flutter, dart

How do we get this overlaying(?) menu that appears and disappears when user clicks on page?***(It seems Swift has this feature)***

When the user taps on the screen, two menus appear on the top & bottom (in addition to the shadow that covers the middle),  and the menus disappear once the user clicks in the shadowed area.

**Note**: The text in the middle has a `longpress` feature and I don't want the menu appearance functionality to interfere with it.
(The app is called Ayah on iOS)

---

### Menu Off:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pydpW.jpg]

### Menu On:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9n36C.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

**Could you describe what You exactly mean with Two menus, or at least include an Image.**

However, if you mean Dialog by that, Then you can basically achieve that in **Flutter** by calling this method:

```
 showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (_) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text(title),
        content: /* Here add your Content widget  */,
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text(okBtnText),
            onPressed: okBtnFunction,
          ),
          FlatButton(
              child: Text(cancelBtnText),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context))
        ],
      );
    });
```

Here's a video from Flutter Widget of the week, explaining the **AlertDialog** widget:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=75CsnyRXf5I